# MyType<T> DataContract is in the Silverlight client MyTypeOfT

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, generics, datacontract

i have a WCF service with a `Property<T> DataContract` (with KnownType, et cetera...), but in the Silverlight client I have just `PropertyOfint, PropertyOfstring, ...` types, but I need in Silverlight also a generic type. How?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Silverlight supports generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soap standard doesn't support the concept of generics so it is not supported directly in WCF. However, you can achieve [this support if you control both the client and the WCF service](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/juveriak/archive/2008/02/03/using-channels-vs-proxies-in-wcf.aspx) by sharing the ServiceContract DLL between the client and the service. Make sure that this is really what you want since it is **not** a recommended SOA best practice.

Here [is an article](http://johnllao.wordpress.com/calling-wcf-from-silverlight-without-using-service-reference/) that describes how this approach works. By sharing the ServiceContract (**not** the service implementation DLL) and using the WCF ChannelFactory class you do not need to generate a proxy class since the ChannelFactory class will do this dynamically for you. The ServiceContract assembly will also need to contain all the referenced DataMember marked classes which is the main flaw of this approach because any logic they contain will also be shared. As long as the DataMember classes are just data transfer objects (DTO) then you're not bending the SOA tenents entirely out of shape. The article also explains how to do this with the WCF ClientBase class.

Comment: Okay, but is it possible something like 'Convert.ChangeType'?

Comment: Not really because the type you would be trying to convert must implement the IConvertible interface which neither "Add Service Reference" or SvcUtil will do. I answered a [question along these lines here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187006/how-to-expose-objects-through-wcf) The answers there (not just mine) may help you understand the limitations of WCF objects. Basically, WCF object are **not** intended to be .NET objects. The closest you can come is sharing contract DLLs which is generally not a good thing.